cuDF installation failure: "Didn't find wheel for cudf-cu12 24.6.1"
I'm trying to install cuDF to gain the glorious powers of multithreading my NVIDIA GPU in my python scripts. However, I can't install cuDF.
To install cuDF, i went to https://docs.rapids.ai/install and ran the created command:
pip install \     --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com \     cudf-cu12==24.6.* dask-cudf-cu12==24.6.* cuml-cu12==24.6.* \     cugraph-cu12==24.6.* cuspatial-cu12==24.6.* cuproj-cu12==24.6.* \     cuxfilter-cu12==24.6.* cucim-cu12==24.6.* pylibraft-cu12==24.6.* \     raft-dask-cu12==24.6.* cuvs-cu12==24.6.*

but it produced an error in which it says "Didn't find wheel for cudf-cu12 24.6.1" (full error message below). In the error message, it even suggests to run the command
$ pip install --extra-index-url https://pypi.nvidia.com cudf-cu12

but that produces the same error message- ironically with that same suggestion within it.
How can I proceed? I installed the CUDA 12 driver, I downgraded my Python to Python 11 as required, I tried the conda install, I tried installing lower versions (CUDA 11 instead of CUDA 12).
Here is the full output from running the pip install:
%pip install \
    --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com \
    cudf-cu12==24.6.* dask-cudf-cu12==24.6.* cuml-cu12==24.6.* \
    cugraph-cu12==24.6.* cuspatial-cu12==24.6.* cuproj-cu12==24.6.* \
    cuxfilter-cu12==24.6.* cucim-cu12==24.6.* pylibraft-cu12==24.6.* \
    raft-dask-cu12==24.6.* cuvs-cu12==24.6.*


Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.nvidia.com
Collecting cudf-cu12==24.6.*   Using cached cudf_cu12-24.6.1.tar.gz
(2.6 kB)   Installing build dependencies: started   Installing build
dependencies: finished with status 'done'   Getting requirements to
build wheel: started   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished
with status 'done'   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error      Preparing metadata
(pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.   exit code: 1      [62
lines of output]   INFO:nvidia-stub:Testing wheel
cudf_cu12-24.6.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_aarch64.whl against tag
cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_aarch64   INFO:nvidia-stub:Testing wheel
cudf_cu12-24.6.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl against tag
cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64   INFO:nvidia-stub:Testing wheel
cudf_cu12-24.6.1-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_28_aarch64.whl against tag
cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_28_aarch64   INFO:nvidia-stub:Testing wheel
cudf_cu12-24.6.1-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl against tag
cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_28_x86_64   INFO:nvidia-stub:Testing wheel
cudf_cu12-24.6.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_28_aarch64.whl against tag
cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_28_aarch64   INFO:nvidia-stub:Testing wheel
cudf_cu12-24.6.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl against tag
cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_28_x86_64     File
"C:\Users\samt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7iipheuq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\nvidia_stub\wheel.py",
line 177, in download_wheel       return
download_manual(wheel_directory, distribution, version)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     File
"C:\Users\samt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7iipheuq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\nvidia_stub\wheel.py",
line 144, in download_manual       raise RuntimeError(f"Didn't find
wheel for {distribution} {version}")   Traceback (most recent call
last):     File
"C:\Users\samt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7iipheuq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\nvidia_stub\wheel.py",
line 177, in download_wheel       return
download_manual(wheel_directory, distribution, version)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     File
"C:\Users\samt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7iipheuq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\nvidia_stub\wheel.py",
line 144, in download_manual       raise RuntimeError(f"Didn't find
wheel for {distribution} {version}")   RuntimeError: Didn't find wheel
for cudf-cu12 24.6.1      During handling of the above exception,
another exception occurred:      Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"C:\Users\samt\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py",
line 353, in        main()     File
"C:\Users\samt\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py",
line 335, in main       json_out['return_val'] =
hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     File
"C:\Users\samt\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py",
line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel       whl_basename =
backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     File
"C:\Users\samt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7iipheuq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\nvidia_stub\buildapi.py",
line 29, in build_wheel       return
download_wheel(pathlib.Path(wheel_directory), config_settings)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File
"C:\Users\samt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7iipheuq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\nvidia_stub\wheel.py",
line 179, in download_wheel       report_install_failure(distribution,
version, exception_context)     File
"C:\Users\samt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7iipheuq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\nvidia_stub\error.py",
line 63, in report_install_failure       raise InstallFailedError(
nvidia_stub.error.InstallFailedError:
*******************************************************************************      The installation of cudf-cu12 for version 24.6.1 failed.      This is
a special placeholder package which downloads a real wheel package
from https://pypi.nvidia.com. If https://pypi.nvidia.com is not
reachable, we   cannot download the real wheel file to install.
You might try installing this package via
$ pip install --extra-index-url https://pypi.nvidia.com cudf-cu12
Here is some debug information about your platform to include in any
bug report:  Python Version: CPython 3.11.9 Operating System: Windows
10 CPU Architecture: AMD64 Driver Version: 555.99 CUDA Version: 12.5
*******************************************************************************  [end of output]  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is
likely not a problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed
Encountered error while generating package metadata.  See above for
output.  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not
pip. hint: See above for details.

I also tried the conda version of the install created from the RAPIDS site:
conda create -n rapids-24.06 -c rapidsai -c conda-forge -c nvidia rapids=24.06 python=3.11 'cuda-version>=12.0,<=12.2'

and that produced:
Channels:
 - rapidsai
 - conda-forge
 - nvidia
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - rapids=24.06*

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia
  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

I just don't know how to proceed. Maybe I need to research how to install wheels?
UPDATE: The error message states I am using microsoft 10, but according to my computer, I am not:

Edition   Windows 11 Pro Version  22H2 Installed on   ‎2/‎4/‎2023 OS
build 22621.3958 Experience   Windows Feature Experience Pack
1000.22700.1026.0

UPDATE: I am now using the WSL2 terminal. I installed anaconda, and I installed RAPIDS as instructed on the website in the WS2L:
conda create -n rapids-24.06 -c rapidsai -c conda-forge -c nvidia  \
    rapids=24.06 python=3.11 'cuda-version>=12.0,<=12.2

And although this was successful, there are still problems. Even inside the WSL2, I cannot import cudf; it gives the module not found error
(base) aridleprechaun@Samuel-Tanner-Desktop:~$ ls
Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Linux-x86_64.sh    Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Windows-x86_64.exe    anaconda3
Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Linux-x86_64.sh.1  Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Windows-x86_64.exe.1
(base) aridleprechaun@Samuel-Tanner-Desktop:~$ python
Python 3.12.4 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Jun 18 2024, 15:12:24) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cudf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cudf' 

cudf should be already be installed when I installed RAPIDS. Proof/verification I installed RAPIDS:
(base) aridleprechaun@Samuel-Tanner-Desktop:~$ conda create -n rapids-24.06 -c rapidsai -c conda-forge -c nvidia  \
    rapids=24.06 python=3.11 'cuda-version>=12.0,<=12.2'
WARNING: A conda environment already exists at '/home/aridleprechaun/anaconda3/envs/rapids-24.06'
Remove existing environment (y/[n])? n


CondaSystemExit: Exiting.


It looks like you're installing on Windows. To use cuDF on windows, you need to use Windows Subsystem for Linux. The RAPIDS install page has a section for installing on WSL that should hopefully get you up and running.

Followed the instructions, but I'm having issues still. I have the WSL2 terminal window, i successfully installed anaconda, but "conda" results in "conda: commnad not found", and I have no other recourse. I even tried "conda-init"

I also tried conda.exe as one page suggested, but no difference.

I was supposed to also run bash Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Linux-x86_64.sh

Clarification:  Now that I have run bash Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Linux-x86_64.sh, RAPIDS is installed successfully on the WSL2. Now I am trying to see if I can get cuDF to work in my Jupyter notebooks, although I do have to leave for the day

Now I have the issue that even though RAPIDS was installed in the WSL2, the cudf library is completely missing. Importing cudf results in module not found error. It should have been installed by installin RAPIDS. I'll write another post for this

The issue seems to be that you haven't activate the virtual environment rapids-24.06. The installation command present in RAPIDS installation page creates a conda virtual environment with conda create
conda activate rapids-24.06 followed up import cudf should hopefully solve things for you. By the way, what are you using cudf for? Are you running into situation where your pandas code is slow?

The issue was that I was trying to install directly from my Window's jupyter notebook (like i would any pip install), but that's not how installing cuDF works. Yes, you could say that pandas is going slowly. At work, I have a 54-billion row  df to work on, and I'm designing the computer workstations, so I need to also test GPU hardware to see what I should order.
